# Elegant way to get subtensor by indices in pytorch?

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

I'm trying to find an elegant way of getting a tensor, containing a list of specific subtensors in pytorch.

Let's say I have a torch tensor `x` of size `[B, W, H, C]`. I check a kind of threshold condition on the channels, which gives me a tensor `cond` of size `[B, W, H]` filled with 0s and 1s. I employ

```
indices = torch.nonzero(cond)
```

which produces a list of shape `[N, 3]` of type `torch.int`. that contains indices on which the condition was satisfied, `N` being the number of found objects. Now, I thought is was logical that

```
x[indices]
```

will yield a tensor of the size `[N,C]`: those subtensors I need. That's not how it works, though, as `__getitem__` with a tensor key effectively calls `torch.index_select`. In order to get what I want, I am forced to call

```
x[list(zip(*indices))]
```

which I find quite cumbersome.

Is there any elegant way to get an `[N,C]` tensor given a list of `N` index tuples, without using lists?